# What are all the ways use_count of std::shared_ptr is incremented?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, shared-ptr, double-free

I have two `shared_ptr`s pointing to the same `int`, i.e. calling `get()` on them returns the same address. But calling `use_count()` on them returns `1`. When the last of them goes out of scope, it tries to free up the memory already freed by the other one, causing a double free runtime error:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    shared_ptr<int> sp1(make_shared<int>(7));
    shared_ptr<int> sp2(&(*sp1));
    cout << sp1.use_count() << endl;  // 1
    cout << sp2.use_count() << endl;  // 1
    cout << sp1.get() << endl;        // same address
    cout << sp2.get() << endl;        // same address
}
// ^ Double free runtime error at closing brace.
```

Same thing happens in this variant with an explicitly declared raw pointer:

```
int main() {
    int *raw_ptr = new int(8);
    shared_ptr<int> sp3(raw_ptr);
    shared_ptr<int> sp4(raw_ptr);
    cout << sp3.use_count() << endl;  // 1
    cout << sp4.use_count() << endl;  // 1
    cout << sp3.get() << endl;        // same address
    cout << sp4.get() << endl;        // same address
}
// ^ Double free runtime error at closing brace.
```

Why does `use_count()` return `1` (but not `2`) if both `shared_ptr`s point to the same thing? If `use_count()` returned `1`, then why was there the attempt to free the `int` twice? I thought that a `shared_ptr` will increase `use_count` by one if and only if it points to the same address as its brethren `shared_ptr`s.

Is a `std::shared_ptr`’s `use_count` incremented only by the first `shared_ptr`'s construction by raw pointer (or assignment to raw pointer, if default-constructed) and then by additional `shared_ptr`s’ copy-construction or assignment by any of the prior `shared_ptr`s? And what are all the other ways of incrementing, if any?

Comment: Try instead `shared_ptr<int> sp4 = sp3;`. You need to copy the shared pointer object itself; creating a new shared pointer with the same raw pointer only means now you have two shared pointers that each think they have exclusive ownership of the object. This is easier if you instead do `shared_ptr<int> sp3(new int(8));` -- don't let the raw pointer be visible in your program to avoid accidentally using it.

Comment: Actually, even better would be `auto sp3 = std::make_shared<int>(8);` as this allows the C++ implementation to allocate room for both the `int` and the `shared_ptr` control block in a single memory allocation. (The standard does not require this optimization, but it does permit it. If you use `shared_ptr<int>(new int(8))` then this optimization is not possible.)

Comment: @cdhowie , Good point. My comment here is just to make it clearer for others that if doing `shared_ptr<int> sp3(new int(8)); shared_ptr<int> sp4(new int(8));`, `sp3` and `sp4` point to different `int`s (at different addresses) that just have the same value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you give a pointer to a `shared_ptr`, that shared pointer takes ownership of that pointer. You are no longer allowed to `delete` it, pass it to another `shared_ptr`, or similar. There's no global lookup table for the new `shared_ptr` to check to find that there's already another `shared_ptr` that already owns the pointer or anything like that.

Put another way, the double free error occurred when the second `shared_ptr` was created by passing in the same pointer rather than copying the `shared_ptr` itself (which increments the use count). The fact that you can't observe the undefined behavior until later doesn't change where it actually occurs.

Comment: So is other `shared_ptr`s' copy-construction and assignment the *only* ways to increase `use_count`?

Comment: @CodeBricks Yes. Otherwise there would have to be some global table of raw pointers so that when you construct a brand new instance from a raw pointer it could go look up the reference count object, and that would require synchronization to the global table in a multithreaded program... it would be a nightmare.

Comment: @codeBricks: The only ways that don't trigger undefined behavior, yeah. (There are a bunch of member functions hanging off `shared_ptr` that may change this; I'm not completely positive for everything; but any other members behave like copy construction or copy assignment in some way)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a copy constructor of shared_ptr to construct the second shared pointer properly.